# About the inequality $\left(\ln\left(\frac{4+x}{2x+2}\right)\right)^{2}\leq x!$

Tags: inequality, logarithms, power-series, gamma-function

### Problem :

Let $-1<x<0$ then we have :

$$\left(\ln\left(\frac{4+x}{2x+2}\right)\right)^{2}\leq x!\tag{I}$$

### My attempt:

---

I have tried :

$$x!=\frac{1}{x+1}-\gamma+O(x^2)$$

Wich is not enought .

Also I have tried derivative without success unfortunately .I think we need more terms in the power series like :

$$x!=\frac{1}{x+1}-\gamma+\frac{1}{12}(6\gamma^2+\pi^2)(x+1)+O(x^2)$$

The problem is we get an upper bound not an lower bound ...

### Motivation

My motivation is to find a sufficiently accurate inverse of the Gamma function : see [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=inverse%20function%20%28ln%28%284%2Bx%29%2F%282x%2B2%29%29%29%C2%B2)

---

### Question :

How to show $(I)$ ?

Thanks.

Comment: So you mean $\Gamma(x+1),$ not $x!$?

Comment: Notice that I wrote *"seems"* . In fact, numerically, it does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the substitution $x = y - 1$, taking logarithm, it suffices to prove that, for all $0 < y < 1$,
$$\ln \Gamma(y) \ge 2\ln \ln \frac{3 + y}{2y}.$$

Using the known property
$$-\ln \Gamma(y) = \ln y + \gamma y + 
\sum_{n=1}^\infty [\ln(1 + y/n) - y/n],$$
we have, for all $0 < y < 1$,
$$\ln \Gamma(y)
\ge - \ln y - \gamma y + \sum_{n=1}^2 [y/n - \ln(1 + y/n)]$$
where we have used $u \ge \ln (1 + u)$ for all $u\ge 0$.

It suffices to prove that, for all $0 < y < 1$,
$$- \ln y + (3/2 - \gamma)y - \ln(1 + y) - \ln(1 + y/2) \ge 2\ln \ln \frac{3 + y}{2y}$$
or
$$(3/2 - \gamma)y - \ln(1 + y) - \ln(1 + y/2) \ge 2\ln \left(\sqrt{y}\ln \frac{3 + y}{2y}\right).$$

**Fact 1**: For all $0 < y < 1$,
$$\sqrt{y}\ln \frac{3 + y}{2y} \le \frac{7770\gamma + 47353}{195804\gamma - 59850} - \frac{8}{63}y.$$
(*Hint*: Use $y = z^2$ and take derivative.)

Using Fact 1, it suffices to prove that
$$(3/2 - \gamma)y - \ln(1 + y) - \ln(1 + y/2) \ge 2\ln \left(\frac{7770\gamma + 47353}{195804\gamma - 59850} - \frac{8}{63}y\right).$$
Denote $f(y) = \mathrm{LHS} - \mathrm{RHS}$. We have
$$f'(y) = (16y - 5)g(y).$$
where
$$g(y) = \frac{(3108\gamma^2 - 5612\gamma + 1425)y^2 + (9324\gamma^2 - 10620\gamma + 9799)y + 6216\gamma^2 - 1900\gamma + 12160}{[(-49728\gamma + 15200)y + 15540
 \gamma + 94706](2 + y)(1 + y)}.$$
It is easy to prove that $g(y) > 0$ for all $0 < y < 1$.
Thus, we have $f'(5/16) = 0$, and $f'(y) < 0$ for all $y\in (0, 5/16)$, and
$f'(y) > 0$ for all $y\in (5/16, 1)$.
Thus, for all $0 < y < 1$,
$$f(y) \ge f(5/16) > 0.$$

We are done.

Answer (score 2):

In this range, showing that $$\Bigg[\log \left(\frac{x+4}{2 x+2}\right)\Bigg]^2 \le x!$$ *seems* to be the same as showing that
$$\log \left(\frac{x+4}{2 x+2}\right)\le \sqrt{x!}$$ Consider the function
$$f(x)=\sqrt{x!}-\log \left(\frac{x+4}{2 x+2}\right)$$
$$f'(x)=\frac{3}{x^2+5 x+4}+\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\Gamma (x+1)} \,\psi ^{(0)}(x+1)$$
$$f''(x)=-\frac{1}{(x+1)^2}+\frac{1}{(x+4)^2}+\frac{1}{4} \sqrt{\Gamma (x+1)} \left(\psi
   ^{(0)}(x+1)^2+2 \psi ^{(1)}(x+1)\right) $$ By inspection $f'(x)=0$ close to $x=-\frac 7{10}$. For this value
$$f\left(-\frac{7}{10}\right)=\sqrt{\Gamma \left(\frac{3}{10}\right)}-\log \left(\frac{11}{2}\right) >0$$ $$f''\left(-\frac{7}{10}\right)=\frac{1}{4} \sqrt{\Gamma \left(\frac{3}{10}\right)} \left(\psi
   ^{(0)}\left(\frac{3}{10}\right)^2+2 \psi
   ^{(1)}\left(\frac{3}{10}\right)\right)-\frac{4000}{363} > 0$$ So, we have the minimum
$$f\left(-\frac{7}{10}\right)=\sqrt{\Gamma \left(\frac{3}{10}\right)}-\log \left(\frac{11}{2}\right)=0.0248672$$ A full minimization of $f(x)$ gives a value of $0.02486720$ at $x=-0.700265$.