# An upper bound for the function $x!$ using some well-know constant as $e$ or $\pi$

Tags: derivatives, inequality, power-series, gamma-function, constants

Problem :

Define :

### $$f(x)=\left(e^{\frac{3x\left(\pi^{x}-e^{x}\right)}{\pi^{x}+e^{x}}}-e^{\sqrt{2x}-3}\right)^{\frac{3}{\pi}}$$

Let $x>\frac{1}{10}$ then prove or disprove that :

$$j(x)=f\left(x\right)\cdot\frac{1}{\left(f\left(0\right)\right)^{\frac{3}{\pi}}}>x!$$

A weaker result

From here ( [About the inequality $\left(\ln\left(\frac{4+x}{2x+2}\right)\right)^{2}\leq x!$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4345123/about-the-inequality-left-ln-left-frac4x2x2-right-right2-leq-x) ) we have (see RiverLi's answer):

$$-\ln \Gamma(x) = \ln x + \gamma x + 
\sum_{n=1}^\infty [\ln(1 + x/n) - x/n],$$

We need to show :

$$\frac{3x\left(\pi^{x}-e^{x}\right)}{\pi^{x}+e^{x}}>\ln x!$$

Unfortunetaly we cannot do the same thing as in RiverLi's answer wich works because it's a lower bound and here a upper bound .

Anyway next I simplify the fraction and tried to use derivative without to reach the desired goal .
Edit :

We can play with the three function :

$$g(x)=\left(x!\right)^{\frac{1}{x}}$$

$$h(x)=x!$$

And :

$$l(x)=\left(\left(xe^{-1}+g\left(0\right)\right)+\left(-\left(\left(\frac{1}{x+a}\right)-\frac{1}{a}\right)\right)^{b}\right)^{x}$$

As good start we can choose :
$$b=1.35,a=2.2$$

Edit 2 :

It seems we have the following inequalities on $(\frac{1}{10},e)$ :

$$j(x)> \left(xe^{-1}+g\left(0\right)+\left(-\frac{1}{x+a}+\frac{1}{a}\right)^{b}\right)^{x}> x!$$

Where $a=3.198$ and $b=1$

Question :

How to show $(I)$ or find a counter-example ?

Ps: All my apologize for the previous question hope here that it's not trivial at all .

Comment: For which $x$ do you want to apparoximate $x!$ ? For large $x$, the Strirling approximation is already extremely tight and the expression on the left side highlighted in blue utterly useless.

Comment: @Peter Hum well I agree with you for large $x$ but for small $x$ it will be a different story . As I said the inequality seems valid for $x>0$ .Thanks you for your reply ( :-:)).

Comment: @Peter. It works for all $x>0$

Comment: @ErikSatie Please check $x = 1/100$.
By the way, I think that you used many redundant parentheses which is not good for reading. You may edit it manually. For example, 1) $\mathrm{e}^{\sqrt{2x} - 3}$ is ok, instead of $e^{\left(\sqrt{2x}-3\right)}$. 2) 
$$l(x)=\left(x\mathrm{e}^{-1}+g\left(0\right)+\left(-\frac{1}{x+a} + \frac{1}{a}
\right)^{b}\right)^{x}$$
is ok, instead of
$$l(x)=\left(\left(xe^{-1}+g\left(0\right)\right)+\left(-\left(\left(\frac{1}{x+a}\right) - \frac{1}{a}\right)\right)^{b}\right)^{x}.$$

Comment: @ErikSatie By the way, I did not downvote you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*All this work has been done solving with (more than nasty) radicals quartic equations generated for approximations.*

Starting with a small detail (already reported by @River Li in comments)
: the inequality $j(x) > \Gamma(x+1)$ does not hold for very small values of $x$ close to $0$.
$$\Delta=j(0) - \Gamma(1)=\left(1-\frac{1}{e^3}\right)^{3\frac{ (\pi -3)}{\pi ^2}}-1 \quad < 0$$ So, if the inequality holds, it will be for $0 < x_* < x $.

Considering the function
$$h(x)=j(x)-\Gamma(x+1)$$ its series expansion around $x=0$ gives a quartic polynomial in $\sqrt x$. Expanded to $O\left(x^{5/2}\right)$, $h(x)=0$ for $\color{blue}{x_0=0.0278927}$ (the "exact" solution being $\color{red}{x_0=0.0278222}$).

Expanding $h'(x)$ as a series around $x=1$ to  $O\left((x-1)^{5}\right)$ shows a maximum value of $h(x)$ for $\color{blue}{x_1=0.760950}$ (the "exact" solution being $\color{red}{x_1=0.761132}$) and $\color{blue}{h(x_1)=0.0888744}$ (the "exact" value being the same).

Expanding $h'(x)$ as a series around $x=e$ to  $O\left((x-e)^{5}\right)$ shows a minimum value of $h(x)$ for $\color{blue}{x_e=2.55947}$  and $\color{blue}{h(x_e)=0.0109763}$.

Similarly, expanding $h''(x)$ around $x=\frac \pi 2$ (this is close to $\frac {x_1+x_e}2$), the inflection is predicted at $\color{blue}{x_i=1.74822}$ (the "exact" value being $\color{red}{x_i=1.74814}$)

Reusing the first series expansion leads to $\color{blue}{x_*=0.0671382}$ (the "exact" value being $\color{red}{x_*=0.0662558}$)

A numerical minimization shows that $\color{red}{x_{\text{min}}=2.55956}$ and
$\color{red} {h({x_{\text{min}}})=0.0109763}$